# binding d3 event in a class

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6, this

I want to pass the instance of my class to the bound d3 drag function.

I try to assign this to a variable and pass that.
I end up with undefined.

I'm a bit confused? How would i access the instance of my class in this case?

Thank you.

```
class foo {

  constructor(a){
    this.a = a;

  }
  method1(){

    var referenceToMyClass = this;  

    this.dragEvent = d3.drag(referenceToMyClass)
    .on("drag", this.method2);

    d3.select('target id').call(this.dragEvent);
  }
  method2(){

   //Here i want to access referenceToMyClass;
   //referenceToMyClass is undefined.
   //this refers to the event target.


  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a function and pass it down in the function you will have access to `this`:

```
class foo {

  constructor(a){
    this.a = a;

  }
  method1(){

    var referenceToMyClass = this;  
    var method2 = function(){
      //do something with referenceToMyClass
    }    
    this.dragEvent = d3.drag(referenceToMyClass)
    .on("drag", method2);

    d3.select('target id').call(this.dragEvent);
  }
}
```

or you can use bind:

```
class foo {

  constructor(a){
    this.a = a;
    this.method2.bind(this);
  }
  method1(){

    var referenceToMyClass = this;  

    this.dragEvent = d3.drag(referenceToMyClass)
    .on("drag", this.method2);

    d3.select('target id').call(this.dragEvent);
  }
  method2(){
   //this refers to the object now.
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but this gives a syntax error.(  Unexpected token =  ) Also i need to access the reference to my class and this (as it refers to event target) in the same method.

Comment: Edited my answer, I was thinking you using an es 6 browser. Ok i have made method2 a function. Since its a function you will have access to this now check it now.

Comment: Yeah i tried this method also, es6 functions work, i use the latest Chrome. I also tried 'use strict;'. Somehow i think = in a method definition in a class is not valid i suppose. Did you try it?

Comment: Ok i think I am using react and in there it allows me to do something like that. have edited my answer again, this should work.

Comment: Ah this seems to be a good idea i will try it and get back to this question. I have to give a break now.

Comment: another way could be to use bind try that and let me know if either works perhaps both should wrk.

Comment: Thank you. The first answer, defining the function in the method (such as init etc. ) resolved my problem. Binding `this` is not suitable for me because then i would loose the event target.